# attaching an eventListener to a button that will appear when clicking another button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, addeventlistener

so basically, I'm working on a to-do list and you have to enter a task with the button 'enter' then the task appears in the UI with a button called 'delete'.

I have trouble attaching event listener to the delete button.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="task1"  >
    <label for="task1" id="tasks">running 10 mile</label><br>
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    
</div>
```

That's the default one .

'''javascript

```
    tasks = []

    btnEnter.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if (labelInput.value !== ''){
        tasks.push(labelInput.value)//if not '' push to the tasks arr

    // to display the last element of the tasks array:
    tasks.slice(-1).map((task , i)=>{
    
    const html =
    `<div id="container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="task${i}"  >
    <label for="task${i}" id="tasks">${task}</label><br>
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </div>`;
    inputDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend',html)

    // to clear the input text;
    labelInput.value ='';   
})

    }else {alert('enter a valid task')};
    
})
```

Comment: That's just a button show your event listener code so far please.

Comment: What is the specific problem? Attaching an event listener to a single element is a well documented process

Comment: I added my js code in the question.
 the problem I have is the event listener is attached to just the default task , but when new tasks appear in the UI it didn't

Answer (score 1):

The problem with attaching an event listener on each of the delete buttons is they don't exist in the DOM when the page first loads. We'll need to attach the event listener on an ancestor of the task items. We can use the `div#container` as the ancestor and insert every new task inside.

```js
  const container = document.querySelector('div#container')

  const html = `
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="task${i}" name="task${i}">
      <label for="task${i}">${task}</label><br>
      <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
  `
  container.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html)
```

And we can attach the one click listener on the container which will delegate the event to any new delete buttons that will be clicked.

```js
  container.addEventListener('click', e => {
    document.querySelectorAll('button.delete').forEach(button => {
      if (button.contains(e.target)) {
        // ...delete the task item
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: it works for the default one but when a new task appears in the UI the delete button doesn't respond 
I will edit my comments and add js code

Comment: It might be because we're inserting each task adjacently to the input form rather than inside of a container. I've edited my answer.